# Static Dropdown items in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I searched a lot but nothing realy helped me. I am beginner and please bear any ignorance

I have a dropdown list in my aspx page. The source of the dropdown is from a sqlsource that I have it in my code behind file. I wanted to add a static item to the top of the dropdown and I was able to add it with below line

```
reportparameter.Items.Insert(0, "-------SELECT----------");
```

how do I set a required field validator on this dropdown with the first value from the code behind. I tried different things and I get an conversion error whenever i submit the page.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that `reportparameter` is the `DropDownList`.

You can use the [`AppendDataBoundItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) property to tell ASP.NET that the DataSource should be appended to the "static" item(s).

You can use the `RequiredFieldValidator`'s [`InitalValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx) property to tell it that this counts as *not selcted*. In your casse you need to set it to 0.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="reportparameter"
                AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">-------SELECT----------</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
       InitialValue="0" 
       ControlToValidate="reportparameter"
       ErrorMessage="Required field!"
       runat="server"/>
```